# How do I keep track of multiple Asynchronous Tasks in this code

Tags: java, android

I am creating an option for the users to pause, or schedule a task.  Based on the program I am limiting it to 2 pauses, that can happen in parallel or in series.  I thought the easiest way to do it was to setup two different Runnables.  However if Task 1 < Task 2, and Task 2 is instigated before the end of Task 1, Task 1 shuts Task 2 down.

For the sake of argument, Task 1 is a 5 second delay, Task 2 is a 10 second delay.  Task 2 gets trigger 1 second into Task 1.    When Task 1 finishes, it appears that Task2 has finished.

threadNumber is an int I set when the task is called to keep track of the results.

They are not acting independent and are being commingled

I broke the Runnables into two distinct elements, triggered by a switch/case.  However that did not isolate the actions as I thought.

public class MultiThreadingActivity extends Activity {

```
    public void StartPause1() {
        hand.postDelayed(run1, delay2);
    }

    Runnable run1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CallFinishedWithResult(threadNumber);
        }
    };
    public void StartPause2() {
        hand.postDelayed(run2, delay2);
    }
    Runnable run2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CallFinishedWithResult(threadNumber);
        }
    };
```

}

I would like the task to be asynchronous, simultaneous and independent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things at the same time, AsyncTask is not the right answer.  AsyncTask works by running all tasks in the order they come in on the same thread.  So task 1 blocks any other task from even starting until its complete.  That also means the exact timing of task 2 is indeterminate.  If you need multiple tasks at the same time, or you need to tightly control timing, use a Thread instead.

Comment: I tried with threads, and even named them and the same thing happened.  Can you give me an idea of what to do for two threads simultaneous and asynchronous please?

Comment: To get threads to run at the same time?  You just start them.  Naming them doesn't matter, that's only a debugging feature.

Comment: Thank you Gabe for your attention.  If you do not mind, how do I know when one thread has finished its task versus another.  I want to set "I am done" message with a thread or task identifier so that the appropriate event handler can start once that thread is complete.  I am spinning between threads, and handlers and can't find my way out of this whirlpool of confusion.  I am very very green here and apologize for my ignorance.